# Get call with Authorization-header converts to OPTIONS call

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am using swagger-ui to create and test my apis calls but in case where I have a GET call with Authorization header it fails and returns ERROR. When I try to debug I found out that it sends this GET call as OPTIONS if Authorization header is present, else as a GET call.

The strange part is with Authorization header the POST call works fine.

```
/urlCode:
get:
  description: Initiate something
  parameters:
    - name: Authorization
      in: header
      description: Authorization token
      required: true
      type: string
    - name: var
      in: query
      description: variable
      required: true
      type: string
      format: string
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS issue. To see what's allowed, web applications must first send an OPTIONS request prior to submitting the actual request (which is why you see OPTIONS and not GET). In order for it to work properly, you must enable CORS on the API itself. Further details can be found in [swagger-ui's repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#cors-support).